# Material Design Components React Styled Buttons

Tags: reactjs, material-design

I'm converting our UI to use material design components (from Bootstrap), and am coming across various little difficulties.

Bootstrap makes it super easy to create secondary buttons, contrast-text/outline buttons etc with their theming classes.

When using material design components I'm using the Button class (in react - https://github.com/material-components/material-components-web-react/tree/master/packages/button), but I can't work out how to create a button with secondary colours.

I also can't work out how to change the size of the button (in Bootstrap you have `btn-[sm|lg|etc]`).

So my question is:
How do I make a button that's coloured with secondary theme colours in material design components for react?

Answer (score 0):

Here are some component demos with material UI: https://material-ui.com/components/buttons/

Secondary colors:

```
<Button variant="contained" color="secondary" >
  Secondary
</Button>
```

Sizing:

```
<Button variant="contained" size="large" > //small, medium, large
  Large Button
</Button>
```

Comment: Hmm...I have seen those, but I'm not using Material-UI. I'm using the official Google components. Perhaps they're not as well developed or something?

Comment: My bad.... I saw material and immediately thought material UI.  Looks like the only option you have is some custom CSS